# Can I check if an expression is type-dependent?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

Something tells me the answer is "no", but I figured I'd ask anyway.

I want to check in a macro whether a specific expression is type-dependent. Here's a motivating example:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void Print(const T &value)
{
    if constexpr (std::default_initializable<std::formatter<T>>)
        std::cout << std::format("{}", value) << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "??\n";
}

#define PRINT(...) Print(__VA_ARGS__)

// ---

struct Unknown {};

template <typename T>
void MaybePrint(const T &value)
{
    PRINT(value);
}

int main()
{
    PRINT(42); // "42"
    PRINT(Unknown{}); // "??", but I want a build error, because the expression is not type-dependent.
    MaybePrint(42); // "42"
    MaybePrint(Unknown{}); // "??", this is ok, since the expression is type-dependent.
}
```

I have a macro that prints any object passed to it (this is for a unit test framework).

If it's not printable, I obviously want a compilation error. But for type-dependent expressions I instead want to print a placeholder (to avoid forcing the user to write `if constexpr (printable<T>) ...` every time).

Comment: Failing `requires` on non-dependent expressions are hard errors, not SFINAE, because there's no substitution

Comment: But, because `Print` puts `T` in a dependent context, you're never going to get a hard error in that `if constexpr`, unless `std::formatter` has a specialization containing a `static_assert` or ill-formed expression.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Aha, so moving `if constexpr` to a macro gives the desired behavior. Do you want to post it as an answer?

Comment: If the goal here is a compilation error at the call site, it will be sufficient to make `PRINT` a real function (with a concept as a parameter: `template<typename T>
concept printable = std::default_initializable<std::formatter<T>>;`), rather than a yucky macro. I just tested it, it works. But, no, there's no way to make it macro voodoo. Macros are just text substitutions, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I want a compilation error only if the user tries to print a non-printable non-dependent expression. I don't want a compilation error if it's dependent, then I want to print a placeholder.

Comment: Try to avoid "C" style macros like this : `#define PRINT(...) Print(__VA_ARGS__)` use variadic templates instead.

Comment: @PepijnKramer This problem can't be solved with templates. More generally, I believe it's impossible to write a decent unit test framework with templates alone ([boost.ut](https://github.com/boost-ext/ut) tried, and I don't like what they ended up with). Even more generally, I believe macros are fine in low-level library code (like any other advanced C++ feature), and only start to be problematic when used in higher level business logic code.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Fair points. Maybe a bit too fast a reaction from me this time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the body of `Print` directly into the macro and tweaking the constraint gives the desired behavior:

```cpp
#define PRINT(...)                                                     \
  {                                                                    \
    if constexpr (requires {                                           \
                    std::formatter<                                    \
                        std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(__VA_ARGS__)>>{}; \
                  })                                                   \
      std::cout << std::format("{}", __VA_ARGS__) << '\n';             \
    else                                                               \
      std::cout << "??\n";                                             \
  }

struct Unknown {};

template <typename T>
void MaybePrint(const T &value) {
  PRINT(value);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4Po3xh9oP

I removed `-stdlib=libc++` from Clang because it appears to have lack of library support for this example, but the underlying concept about hard errors vs. substitution failures works the same way in Clang as in GCC and MSVC.

As pointed out by [@SamVarshavchik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77469345/can-i-check-if-an-expression-is-type-dependent/77469433#comment136574115_77469345), you could also move the constraint to the function parameter to get the desired behavior as well:

```cpp
template <class T>
concept printable = std::default_initializable<std::formatter<T>>;

void Print(const printable auto &value) {
  std::cout << std::format("{}", value) << '\n';
}

struct Unknown {};

template <typename T>
void MaybePrint(const T &value) {
  if constexpr (printable<T>) {
    Print(value);
  }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/1MzWhKzrM

Comment: I didn't even need to change the `if constexpr` condition, seemed to work as is for me.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat GCC still passed if `PRINT` failed in a non-dependent context when using your original constraint: https://godbolt.org/z/Thboe83d6

Comment: Aha, I see. Regarding `if constexpr` in `MaybePrint` - that's something I want to avoid, because I don't want the library user to manually write that `if constexpr`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ah, I just thought you could provide a `Print` and `MaybePrint` as part of your library.